# rename field in mongoDB and set newValue at the same time

Tags: mongodb, set, rename

I want to rename a field in MongoDB, then setting new Value with the old field Name: here is the example :

```
 db.exemption.update({'ref':163},{$rename: 
 {'request.reference':'request.oldRef'},$set:
 {'request.reference':'00000'}},true,true)
```

but heri the error that I got

```
{ [MongoError: Cannot update 'request.reference' and 'request.reference' at the same time]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16837,
  err: 'Cannot update \'request.reference\' and \'request.reference\' at the same time' }
```

Is there a possible way to do the update of this field inspite of using 2 queries mongo?

Comment: Not possible with a single update operation but rather two; the first one with the `$rename` and the next with the `$set`

Comment: okk!! i wanted to optimize my code :/

Comment: Any ides of $unset and $rename in the same query ?.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 db.exemptions.update({ref: <value>}, {
     $unset: {'request.oldRef': 1},
     $set: {'request.reference': <new value>}
 });
```

It doesn't really *rename* the field, but it gives you the same result.

Comment: noo, i want to keep the old value of the field 'request.reference' that is why i have renamed the field, and i want to change the value of the field  'request.reference' at the same time, 'request.oldRef' didn't exist ; that iq why there is no need to unset it

Comment: @chou, first off, you should edit your question to reflect that. Second, so you want 'request.oldRef' to equal the original 'request.reference' and 'request.reference' to equal a new value?